# Using Whois to iterate through file with ip addresses

Tags: bash

I have a script so far that gets the ip addresses that visited my site:

```
sudo awk '{ print $1 } ' /var/log/httpd/access_log | sort | uniq > ~/bad_ips.out
```

I’m trying to iterate through those ip addresses with whois and rewrite to the initial file with the list of unique countries that the ips are from.

I can do them individually like so for example:

```
whois -l 93.94.186.228 | grep 'country'
whois -l 93.94.186.228 | grep 'country' | awk '{print $2}'
```

But I’m unsure how to iterate through each in the file, any help would be appreciated

Comment: And here comes xargs `.... | xargs whois -l | .....`

Comment: @kamil cuk Thank you! Could you clarify how this works, I’ve never used xargs before?

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` probably meets your criteria. It basically runs the given command for each line you pass to its stdin. You can see more details at `man xargs`.

You can also reduce the commands in the pipeline by using `-u` option of `sort` and using `awk` itself to match the pattern `country`.

This would do what you'd want:

```
awk '{print $1} ' /var/log/httpd/access_log | sort -u | xargs whois -l |  awk '/country/{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop if every entry is on a new line:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo $line
done < $1
```

Use the script like so:

```
./nameOfScript fileWithIps.txt
```